# Passing calculated data over a WCF service layer for reporting

Tags: asp.net, wcf, reporting, wcf-data-services, dashboard

I'm not really sure how to best word this. We have an ASP.NET web application with the backend services accessible over a WCF service layer. We need to add some reporting/dashboard type bits to the web application.

To make it scalable the data needed for the reporting needs to be calculated on the backend. I'm just wondering if there is a recommended way to pass this data around. It doesn't make much sense to have different service methods to get the different bits of data, it feels like it should be summarised already.

I had a look at WCF Data Services, but that seems more for retrieving full object trees. Maybe some sort of XML document so extra items can be added to the summary without needing service layer changes?

The data would be things like number of orders today, number of orders specific to the person running it, open orders outstanding etc.

Does anyone have any pointers?

Thanks for your time

Comment: Just read that all aggregate functions are unsupported by WCF Data Services

Answer (score 1):

You can look at something like ASP.NET Web API and use an XML Formatter for your data. You can use ViewModels to flatten your data and send over the wire to your web app to bind to grids or whatever you need to.

Basically you would get request (filters, keywords, etc) from your web app, send the parameters to your reporting back-end, retrieve the reporting data, map the values to your ViewModels and serialize them using Web API. Using Web API you can use all kinds of formatters for your data to XML, CSV and JSON to vCard, iCal, PDF, etc...

You can read more about it here: http://www.asp.net/web-api